# how can I restrict users with 64 bit devices to install my Android app?

Tags: android, 64-bit

I am working on an Android app that uses a framework that only works with 64 bit devices.

So, how can I restrict users with 64 bit devices to install my app?

Comment: I have tried to find it out, but faild. Probably you could have a better luck. I'm sure that keyword `ARM64 architecture` is what you need